# getaddrinfo error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: macos, unix, dns, posix, getaddrinfo

When I tryed to get IP address for DNS name with getaddrinfo I got the following error

> getaddrinfo error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

What does this error means? 
Is it possible that getaddrinfo can't resole the DNS name?
But nslookup works fine for this address.  I tryed to call getaddrinfo without port, and without AI_NUMERICSERV flag with the same result.

What is wrong with my call?   OS X 10.11 plaftorm.

This is the sample code

```
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;
int rv;

printf("hostname: %s port: %s ", hostname, port);

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // use AF_INET6 to force IPv6
hints.ai_flags=AI_DEFAULT|AI_NUMERICSERV;
if ( (rv = getaddrinfo( hostname , port , &hints , &servinfo)) != 0)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was connected with sandboxing mechanism on Mac OS X .
I forget about the fact that my application is sandboxed.
Make sure that you have the following lines in your entitlements file.

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
<true/>
```

If you application is not sandboxed getaddrinfo() works as expected.