# Delphi FMX Mac app not connecting to internet when configured for "Application Store" using Indy

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy

I developed an Apple app that I am testing on a Mac Mini. When I set the Delphi configuration to "Normal" then build and run the app on the Mac, the program starts up and connects to the internet without problems. Once the program has been built and run on the Mac, I can go into the `scratch-dir` folder on the Mac (created by Delphi's PSServer) and run the "app" file without problems also.

However, when I change the configuration to "Application Store", rebuild, then use the Deploy button to create the "app" and "pkg" files on the Mac, the app will no longer work when trying to access the internet. Any internet access attempt fails. This happens with both the rebuilt "app" file in the `scratch-dir` folder, and when I install the "pkg" file and try to run the program.

Note: this app uses the Indy components `TIdFTP` and `TIdSMTP` to access an FTP server and to send emails. Both of these work with the "Normal" app, and both fail with the "Application Store" app. The fact that both components fail with the "Application Store" build probably indicates that this is not an Indy problem. But just in case, for the FTP connection, I just get an "Unable to connect to FTP" message that is from my program, I have not added additional error handling to see what fails with the FTP. For the email failure, Indy raises an "Error resolving Address smtp.office365.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (8)" exception.

Any suggestions on how to determine why my "Application Store" build isn't working?

Additional info on 2023-01-03. Just simply changing from Normal configuration to Store Application and doing a deploy causes the problem. I checked the messages given out by Delphi during the builds and the Normal and Store build messages match. For the deploy, only difference in messages is the Normal configuration does a quick compile (not build) and the Store configuration adds the "Apple Distribution" and "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" info to the deployment.

Comment: It would be helpful to know if the FTP connection is failing with the same error as the SMTP connection. But in general, this sounds like a DNS issue within the "Application Store" environment. In Delphi non-Windows platforms, Indy uses the Posix `getaddrinfo()` function to resolve a hostname to an IP address. Are you running on an IPv6-only network, and have you configured the FTP/SMTP components to use IPv6? Indy defaults to IPv4. Is your app sandboxed? If so, did you [enable network entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40975734/65863) to let `getaddrinfo()` work in a sandbox?

Comment: I would not have thought it would affect name resolution, but you may like to try enabling the `Outgoing network socket for connecting` entitlement in the Entitlement List in Project Options for your Delphi project

Comment: I did not enable the network entitlements, as I am not using the sandbox stuff, as far as I know. As mentioned before, the only difference in the two "app" files is that one was compiled using the "Normal" configuration, and the other using the "Application Store" configuration. Running on same Mac, from same folder. No other changes. Note: when I view the file contents of the app files, the file names and structures are the same. The pkg app file contains the same stuff. Also, none of the apps were downloaded from the Mac Store, just compiled and tested on Mac.

Comment: To answer Remy's other question, network is IPv4.

Comment: Remy - is there some way to set up either the TIPFTP or TIdSMTP so I can log the information being sent and received by the components, so I can see what errors are happening internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by both Remy Lebeau and Dave Nottage, the problem with the Application Store compile was not having `Outgoing network socket for connecting` checked in the Entitlement List for the Mac. Checking that option allows the Application Store compile to access the internet.

Note: not sure why compiling the project when set to Normal configuration does not require `Outgoing network socket for connecting` but the Application Store compile does. Makes things confusing and causes a lot of head scratching.